# React native Task :app:processDebugResources FAILED Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0

Tags: android, reactjs, build, expo

Task :app:processDebugResources FAILED

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.0.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
670 actionable tasks: 3 executed, 667 up-to-date

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
> Unable to delete directory 'C:\Users\mayan\Desktop\Yawlit-typeScript\android\app\build\generated\not_namespaced_r_class_sources\debug\r\androidx\appcompat' after 10 attempts

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 5s

Answer (score 0):

Try:
npx react-native run-android

Comment: I've already tried npx react-native run-android, still didn't worked